# eclipse environment in sync on two machines

Tags: eclipse

Has anyone found a good way to keep the Eclipse IDE environment mostly in sync between two machines?  I am not so concerned with the "workspace" folder as I am with the libraries and tools I have installed.  I am using a Mac Mini for most of my development, but my other computer is a Windows 7 machine.

I need to upgrade a library with API changes.  I want to test my app on both machines so that I can compare the old API to the new API, so it would be ideal to have the basic Eclipse environment between the two machines as close as possible.

04/29/2015 clarification based on answer so far:
I am NOT talking about the projects or the workspace, only the overall eclipse environment, things like plugins and tools.  For instance, this may be as simple as copying a certain folder.

By the way, if I were talking about keeping projects in sync, the best way to do that is via GIT or SVN or some other revision control tool.  This would even work for the entire "workspace" folder, I suppose.

Comment: The answer could be as simple as zipping up the more up to date Eclipse and unzipping it on the other machine.  Your eclipse.exe is probably different for the two environments.  I'd be **very careful** about making changes to either Eclipse.  Make sure you zip your Eclipse before you make any changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse "project" is not supposed to be synchronised between computers. But you may checkout project and import it from scratch. As for me it is too complicated
You have to use any build system ant/maven/gradle to do build and test your project from cli without eclipse. Or you may build ant/maven project directly from eclipse.

Comment: I am not talking about the project.  As I said, I don't really care about the workspace folder, which includes the project ( normally ). I am talking about the eclipse environment.  Like I said, I am more concerned with tools and libraries I installed.  Basically, I have installed lots of stuff on my Mac Mini, and I don't want to miss something on my Windows machine.

Comment: Another way to ask this, maybe is:  how do I keep the eclipse plugins in sync between two computers, or virtually in sync.  For instance, maybe I just need to copy a folder from one machine to the other to keep the the Eclipse Environments ( not projects or workspace!!! ) in sync.